# How to send multiple return values in one WCF request?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, request, response

Here is what the WCF service is i want to get 5 values from the users simultaneously and send them the response of addition of first two values as AddedResult, substraction of added result and third value as SubtractedResult, multiplication of SubtractedResult and fourth value as MultipliedResult and division of multipliedResult and 5th value as DividedResult.

I know this looks non-sense but i am trying to do some advance testings with these but i am new to WCF anyone who can help will really be appreciated.

```
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    string GetValuesForCalculation(int value1, int value2, int value3, int value4, int value5);


    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}


public class Service1 : IService1
{

    public int GetValuesForCalculation(int value1, int value2, int value3, int value4, int value5)
    {
        int AddedResult;
        int SubtractedResult;
        int MultipliedResult;
        int DividedResult;

        AddedResult = (value1 + value2);
        SubtractedResult = (AddedResult - value3);
        MultipliedResult = (SubtractedResult - value4);
        DividedResult =(MultipliedResult/value5);

        return AddedResult;
        return SubtractedResult;
        return MultipliedResult;
        return DividedResult;
    }


}
```

How do I return 4 values at the same time?

Comment: I edited your post to make your actual question more clear. feel free to change it if I was wrong in my interpretation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make a `DataContract` and return that object.

```
[ServiceContract()]
interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    ReturnValue GetValuesForCalculation(int value1, int value2, int value3, int value4, int value5);
}


public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public ReturnValue GetValuesForCalculation(int value1, int value2, int value3, int value4, int value5)
    {
        int AddedResult;
        int SubtractedResult;
        int MultipliedResult;
        int DividedResult;

        AddedResult = (value1 + value2);
        SubtractedResult = (AddedResult - value3);
        MultipliedResult = (SubtractedResult - value4);
        DividedResult =(MultipliedResult/value5);

        var returnValue = new ReturnValue(AddedResult, SubtractedResult, MultipliedResult,DividedResult); 

        return returnValue ;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class ReturnValue
{
    public ReturnValue(int addedResult, int subtractedResult, int multipliedResult, int dividedResult)
    {
        AddedResult = addedResult;
        SubtractedResult = subtractedResult;
        MultipliedResult = multipliedResult;
        DividedResult = dividedResult;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int AddedResult {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public int SubtractedResult {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public int MultipliedResult {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public int DividedResult {get; set;}
}
```

On your client side that `ReturnValue` class will be automatically generated by the same code that generates your client proxy (be it the tool built in to visual studio or [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx))

Here is the [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) on `DataContracts`.

Comment: Hi Scott everything is fine with your answer thanks for the reply but i dont know if i am making the mistake the result is null nothing comes up.

Comment: I updated my answer, did you add the `[DataMember]` to each item (you will need to remake the proxy class after you add them)? Also if you step though using a debugger are you sure the value `returnValue` is not null before you send off the reply or is it not null on the sending side but null on the receiving side?

Comment: Got it scott i found my error thank u very much for you answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a struct and return them all in the same call.

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{

public int GetValuesForCalculation(int value1, int value2, int value3, int value4, int value5)
{
    int AddedResult;
    int SubtractedResult;
    int MultipliedResult;
    int DividedResult;

    AddedResult = (value1 + value2);
    SubtractedResult = (AddedResult - value3);
    MultipliedResult = (SubtractedResult - value4);
    DividedResult =(MultipliedResult/value5);

    CallResponse myResponse = new CallREsponse {AddResult = AddedResult, 
                 SubtractResult = SubtractedResult, 
                 MultiplyResult = MultipliedResult, 
                 DivideResult = DividedResult};
    return myResponse;
}


}
public struct CallResponse
{
int AddResult;
    int SubtractResult;
    int MultiplyResult;
    int DivideResult;
}
```

Comment: You can use a struct for returning values with WCF without a DataContract or makring it Serializeable? Never knew.

Comment: I believe you should be able to.  I have done it with classes before with setting any serializable attributes or data contract attributes.  The only real reason to specify the data contract is when you want full control over what is returned.  Otherwise, it will do it automatically

Comment: Hi brian it says that the parameters inside new callresponse are inaccessible due to protection level but hey thaks for the reply

Comment: @BikramGc You need to put public in front of each item inside of the struct.

Comment: Sorry about that, Scott is right, you need a public in front of them.  I just quickly typed that up in Notepad, so you may need to tweak it some.